# getRetweetCount in Twitter4j giving incorrect results?

Tags: twitter, twitter4j

In my timeline @ my twitter home page,it shows that my status has been retweeted by a particular user,but the code below returns ZERO?Why?

```
    Twitter twitter=new TwitterFactory().getInstance(); 
    try{
    User u= twitter.verifyCredentials();
    Status s=u.getStatus();
    System.out.println("@"+u.getScreenName()+"-"+s.getText());
    System.out.println("\nNumber of Retweets-"+s.getRetweetCount());
    System.out.println(s.getCreatedAt());
    }
    catch(TwitterException e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

The status is confirmed by the creation date and the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That works now, perhaps the `twitter4j` source wasn't updated.Anyways,I didn't expect this.

Comment: I am using Twiiter4J stream twitter4j-stream-3.0.3.jar and it is returning getRetweetCount() as 0. which version are you using ? or have you done any changes ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
s.getRetweetedStatus().getRetweetCount()
```

not

```
s.getRetweetCount()
```

and also check if it is null. Because not every tweet retweeted. In version twitter4j-core 4.0.4, I used it.